# How do I remove Sublime Merge integration from sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimemerge

I simply don't want them, prefer the git command line, but they are added to my commands as if they were installed, even if I never installed sublime merge.

[image: sublime merge commands]

Is there a way to remove them completly from sublime text command panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting `show_git_status` controls this:

```
    // Shows git repository information next to files in sidebar and in
    // the status bar. Sublime Text has to be restarted for this to take
    // effect.
    "show_git_status": true,
```

It defaults to being turned on, but setting it to `false` and restarting Sublime will disable the general git support, which also stops the command palette entries from appearing, as well as the context menu entries.

Comment: Oh ok, this does removes it, but is there a way to do so preserving general git support? Just want to get those commands out of the palette

Comment: The only way to remove the command palette items and the context menu entries would be to create an override on the associated files from the `Default` package to stop them from being there, as far as I'm aware. If you go that route, your change will mask updates to those files in future versions of Sublime. My `OverrideAudit` package can help you create the overrides as well as warn you. I can update the answer to include more info on both if desired.

Comment: I understand how to do that, just thought it wasn't going to be that much complex. Thanks!

Comment: This works great, and you can use an alternate Sublime package for Git like Githubinator to maintain git powers

Answer (score 1):

Starting with sublime 4 build 4121 we can now just set:

```
"sublime_merge_path": null
```

This will remove sublime merge integration, while preserving general git support